# Deluge permissions on a Synology NAS

Tags: permissions

I installed [Deluge](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/About) through [this guide](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?p=339216#p339216). I have a Synology DS212+.

To summarize: I installed Debian [chroot](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) (from the SynoCommunity repository). Through that I installed the packages deluged (server software) and deluge-web (webinterface). That way I can control the server side through the various clients available on different desktops.

It works quite well, except for one part: permissions. Whenever I add a torrent it creates the files and folders with `drwxr-xr-x` permissions. That way I'm not able to do anything (delete, rename, edit) with the files and folders in other environments. It looks like this when I do a `dir` command:

```
drwxrwxrwx    3 media    users         4096 Sep 30 15:34 .
drwxrwxrwx    4 media    users         4096 Sep 30 13:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Sep 30 15:24 Die Hard (1988)
```

What I want is torrent files and folders created by deluge to be writable (`drwxrwxrwx`), in the users group, and made by the user media.

To be honest I have no idea where to start looking and what part is responsible for this (synology part? chroot? deluge? the mount command that I executed on the download folder?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking around on other places I found the answer. Following the instructions [here](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/DebianUbuntuInitd) and setting the umask to 0, I managed to set the permissions the way I want it.